# recurrence formula for *i*-th Chern class of $CP^n$

Tags: chern-classes, characteristic-classes, kahler-differentials, complex-manifolds

one can show that the relation between first Chern class and second Chern class of $CP^n$ is

$\frac{2(n+1)}{n} c_2 (M)=c_1 (M)^2$

here $c_1 (M)^2=c_1 (M)∧c_1 (M)$.
So is there any recurrence formula for *i*-th Chern class of $CP^n$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for a recurrence formula. If $h\in \mathrm H^2(\mathbb C\mathbb P^n, \mathbb Z)$ is the Poincaré dual of a hyperplane section, then $h^i$ generates $\mathrm H^{2i}(\mathbb C\mathbb P^n, \mathbb Z)$ for all $i = 0, \dots, n$. Then it follows from the Euler sequence that
$$
\mathrm c_i(\mathbb C\mathbb P^n) = \binom{n+1}{i}h^i.
$$

Comment: Angelo -- I completely agree with what you say.  However, perhaps the OP was also thinking about how to express powers of $c_1$ in terms of the other classes: a problem that leads directly to the Segre classes (in the relative setting).

Comment: Dear Jason, would you please explain  with more details

Comment: To Jason: well, in this particular case $c_1^i$ is a multiple of $c_i$, so you don't see the Segre classes.

Comment: Dear Jason, for more information you can see the reason of Angelo in following explanatory paper 
http://www.math.columbia.edu/~tosatti/cpn.pdf

Comment: Angelo: Of course you are right in the absolute setting, I was guessing (probably wrongly) that the OP had in mind something broader (the relative case, which leads to Segre classes, as I am sure you already know).

Comment: @Haskell -- "Dear Jason, would you please explain with more detail".  Please Google "Segre classes".